# You create an object of type ANumber. The class is defined as follows.What is the value of _number after the code is executed?

Tags: c#

After creating an instance of `Anumber` using the code below, the value of the private `_number` field is 3, not 7. Can someone explain why this is so?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Anumber anumber = new Anumber(3);
        }
    }

    class Anumber
    {
        private int _number = 7;

        public Anumber()
        {

        }

        public Anumber(int num)
        {
            _number = num;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, several of us can. This seems like homework that *you're* supposed to answer though.

Comment: Well I can't. There is nothing in this code named `_number`.

Comment: **after** the code is executed the program will be finished and non-existent...

Comment: This is just laziness - there is no problem to solve here. Use a debugger - run it and see.

Comment: I am trying to unerstand so i need a explanation

Comment: please at least try and provide an explanation of which you think that it might explain the behaviour... May be then some one will be willing to correct it and help you

Comment: @patrick StackoverFlow is not a classroom. This is some really basic code so i suggest you ask your teacher for help if you don't get it.

Comment: when i saw the question i felt the answer in _number will be 7 because integers are value types and we are doing pass by value not pass by reference so i thought that _number will be 7 but the answer is 3 so i need a explanation why _number will be 3 in this situation. no where we are passing it by reference i hope there will be another answer for that Thanks

Comment: This is not a basic question this is certification question and the community should still help people like us. dont forget u also started just like me

Comment: The question you were asked is in regards to what order things run: do constructors run first, or do field initializers run first? You are confusing yourself with "passing by reference/value" in this case. I can't find a suitable answer on SO at the moment so [here's the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @patrick if you run the code above through a debugger one line at a time you will see when `_number` is initialized to 7, and when 3 gets assigned and what the value of it is before exiting the program. The debugger is your friend - use it! It can answer all sorts of "how does this work" or "why did this happen" type questions.

Comment: @Theo I really appreciate what you are doing after you explained me i used the debugger just some where i got confused with pass by value/pass by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class member fields (like `_number`) are initialized before the constructor code is executed, so `_number` will be 7 for a very brief period before the constructor reassigns it's value to 3;